# Multiple MapReduce Functions or Aggregate Frameworks for unique value and count in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am a bit new to mapReduce and aggregation as well within MongoDB.

Here's an example of the dataset:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("521002161e0787522098d110"), "userId" : 4545454, "pickId" : 1, "answerArray" : [  "yes" ], "city" : "New York", "state" : "New York" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("521002481e0787522098d111"), "userId" : 64545454, "pickId" : 1, "answerArray" : [  "no" ], "city" : "New York", "state" : "New York" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("521002871e0787522098d112"), "userId" : 78263636, "pickId" : 1, "answerArray" : [  "yes" ], "city" : "Albany", "state" : "New York" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5211507c1e0787522098d113"), "userId" : 78263636, "pickId" : 2, "answerArray" : [  "yes" ], "city" : "New York", "state" : "New York" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5211507c1e0787522098d113"), "userId" : 78263636, "pickId" : 1, "answerArray" : [  "yes" ], "city" : "Wichita", "state" : "Kansas" }
```

I am looking to get a list of unique values of state, city, pickId, answerArray and then count those unique combinations.  The result would need to look like this:

```
{"pickId": 1, "city": "New York", "state": "New York", "answerArray": ["yes"], "count":2}
{"pickId": 1, "city": "Albany", "state": "New York", "answerArray": ["no"], "count":1}
{"pickId": 1, "city": "New York", "state": "New York", "answerArray": ["no"], "count":1}
{"pickId": 1, "city": "Wichita", "state": "Kansas", "answerArray": ["yes"], "count":1}
```

The issue I am having is that mapReduce only takes two arguments:

```
Error: fast_emit takes 2 args near...
```

But I am looking to map multiple unique values onto one pickId.

Here is the code in mapReduce I am looking at:

```
var mapFunct = function() {
if(this.answerArray == "yes"){
emit(this.pickId,1);}
else{
emit(this.pickId,0);};}

var mapReduce2 = function(keyPickId,answerVals){ 
return Array.sum(answerVals);};

db.answers.mapReduce( mapFunct, mapReduce2, { out: "mapReduceAnswers"})
```

Any help or further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I have looked into aggregate frameworks as well, but it doesn't seem I will be getting the kind of output I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the format you want using aggregation, specifically the `$group` and `$project` operators. Take a look at this aggregation call:

```
var agg_output = db.answers.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: {
                city: "$city",
                state: "$state",
                answerArray: "$answerArray",
                pickId: "$pickId"
            }, count: { $sum: 1 }}
  },
  { $project: { city: "$_id.city", 
                state: "$_id.state", 
                answerArray: "$_id.answerArray", 
                pickId: "$_id.pickId", 
                count: "$count", 
                _id: 0}
  }
]);

db.answer_counts.insert(agg_output.result);
```

The `$group` stage takes care of summing the occurences of each unique combination of city/state/answerArray/pickId, while the `$project` stage puts the data into the form you want.

The `insert` call saves the resulting output to a new collection. Does that make sense?